# gganimate unable to call ImageMagick correctly, possible path error

Tags: r, gganimate

I  am trying to install gganimate in Windows 7. I have already added Path to ImageMagick and below are the codes I used in my attempt to install it.

```
library(httr)
set_config(config(ssl_verifypeer = 0L))
library(devtools)
library(RCurl)
devtools::install_github("RcppCore/Rcpp")
devtools::install_github("dgrtwo/gganimate")
install.packages("gapminder")
library(gapminder)
library(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_bw())
p <- ggplot(gapminder, aes(gdpPercap, lifeExp, size = pop, color =continent,   frame = year)) +
geom_point() +
scale_x_log10()

library(gganimate)

install.packages("cowplot")
install.packages("animation")
library(animation)
ani.options(convert = shQuote('C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-7.0.3-  Q16/magick.exe'))
gganimate(p)
```

But I get the following error after I run the last line gganimate(p):
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwAAe.png)

The error is:

> Executing: 
>   ""\"C:/Program
>       Files/ImageMagick-7.0.3-Q16/magick.exe\""
>       -loop 0 -dispose none -delay 0
>       plot1.png -dispose previous
>       -delay 100 plot2.png plot3.png
>       plot4.png plot5.png plot6.png
>       plot7.png plot8.png plot9.png
>       plot10.png plot11.png plot12.png
>       plot13.png "fileb4835f936f2.gif""
>   The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
>   an error occurred in the conversion... see Notes in ?im.convert
>   Error in file(file, "rb") : cannot open the connection
>   In addition: Warning messages:
>   1: running command 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c "\"C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-7.0.3-Q16/magick.exe\"" --version' had status 1 
>   2: running command 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c ""\"C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-7.0.3-Q16/magick.exe\"" -loop 0 -dispose none -delay 0 plot1.png -dispose previous -delay 100 plot2.png plot3.png plot4.png plot5.png plot6.png plot7.png plot8.png plot9.png plot10.png plot11.png plot12.png plot13.png "fileb4835f936f2.gif""' had status 1 
>   3: In cmd.fun(convert) :
>     '""\"C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-7.0.3-Q16/magick.exe\"" -loop 0 -dispose none -delay 0 plot1.png -dispose previous -delay 100 plot2.png plot3.png plot4.png plot5.png plot6.png plot7.png plot8.png plot9.png plot10.png plot11.png plot12.png plot13.png "fileb4835f936f2.gif""' execution failed with error code 1
>   4: running command '""\"C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-7.0.3-Q16/magick.exe\"" -loop 0 -dispose none -delay 0 plot1.png -dispose previous -delay 100 plot2.png plot3.png plot4.png plot5.png plot6.png plot7.png plot8.png plot9.png plot10.png plot11.png plot12.png plot13.png "fileb4835f936f2.gif""' had status 127 
>   5: In file(file, "rb") :
>     cannot open file 'C:\Users\shammun\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpuSfr4m/gganimate\fileb4835f936f2.gif': No such file or directory

Answer (score 4):

Changing path using `shortPathName` function in `ani.options` worked for me:

```
magickPath <- shortPathName("C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-7.0.3-Q16\\magick.exe")
ani.options(convert=magickPath)
```

Comment: Thank you! Had been looking for a solution for 30 minutes before this :)

Answer (score 0):

I found that the space in the path name was causing me problems. I changed the path name from

```
ani.options(convert = "C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-7.0.3-Q16/magick.exe")
```

to

```
ani.options(convert = "C:/PROGRA~1/ImageMagick-7.0.3-Q16/magick.exe")
```

and then I was able to save GIFs again